# Hi I create new task in Gulp for compile Js file with Jsx code using Babel but it get error - Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, gulp, babeljs

Gulp for compile Js  file with Jsx  code using Babel but it get error - Unexpected token

`gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/badge.js')
      .pipe(babel())//require("gulp-babel")
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
   });`

[image: error]

Comment: Sorry for confusion and bad code editing, below is the detail of my question.

Comment: I try to get raect demo Getting Started  - there is the sample that use  **browser.min.js** on the Client to parse JSX syntax use script **type="text/babel**.  But I do not want to use browser.min.js, I want to compile it before using **Gulp** task

Comment: I found one solusion

Comment: This working fine when **REACTIFY  transform**  is using. But  I can't undestand why it is not workind when BABELIFY transform is used insted of REACTIFY  (.transform(babelify)//require("babelify"))?                                 `gulp.task('build', function () {
    return browserify('app/badge.js', { debug: true })
        .transform(reactify)//require("reactify")
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});`

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly tell `babel` what you want to transform.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react
```

and use

```
.pipe(babel({
  presets: ['react', 'es2015']
}))
```

Same if you want to use `babelify`.

Answer (score 1):

Many Thanks for help. I use **Visual Studio 2015** (it is a little difficult to work with NPM)

```
    I was because As of Babel 6.0.0 there are no plugins included by default
```

I add them to package.json 
    
    `"babel-preset-react": "6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.0.15"`

### And I get the working code sample:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
`return gulp.src('./app/badge.js')
    .pipe(babel({
    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
    })) //require("gulp-babel")       
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
`
```

### And when need to use browserify babelify transform

```
`
gulp.task('default', function () {
var bundler = watchify(browserify({
    entries: ['./app/app.js'],
    transform: [babelify.configure({
        presets: ["es2015", "react"]
    })],
    extensions: ['.js'],
    debug: true,
    cache: {},
    packageCache: {},
    fullPaths: true
}));

function build(file) {
    if (file) gutil.log('Recompiling ' + file);
    return bundler
      .bundle()
      .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
      .pipe(source('main.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
};
build();
bundler.on('update', build);
});
`
```